# Join files in the cloud

Tags: dropbox, cloud, join

I have a Dropbox/One Drive/Google Drive account. I also have a very large file to be uploaded (12GB). My internet connectivity is limited, so I will not be able to upload the file in one go. Is there any method by which I can split the file in my PC and after the pieces get uploaded, combine them in the cloud so that I can save my original file there?

Comment: You could use WinRar to compress the file into multiple rar files and upload them separately. I am not sure, however, how to combine them in the cloud. It might be better to leave them split, as you say your connection is limited.

Comment: A lot of those services can cope with interruptions ... so you don't necessarily need to break down the uploads. You can use any compression tool you like to break a file in smaller pieces, but you won't be able to extract them to the original file IN the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both DropBox and Google Drive actually break up large files and upload them in chunks.  Thats how DropBox is able to do things like "streaming sync".  It all happens without the knowledge of the end user.

I would also look into resumable uploads from the Google Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable

Streaming Sync Announcement:  https://blog.dropbox.com/2014/07/introducing-streaming-sync-supercharged-sync-for-large-files/